# Algebraic Equation $x-2/(x-1)=1-2/(x-1)$ has no solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Equation like 
$x-2/(x-1)=1-2/(x-1)$ has either no solution or just one solution which is 1.if the equation has no solution then why it has no solution...what would be the condition for such equation through which we can find that the given equation has no solution.anyone can explain this phenomena.thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what "such equation" is. The question is quite unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$
x - \frac{2}{x-1} = 1 - \frac{2}{x-1}
$$
doesn't have a solution. What this means is that there are no real numbers that satisfy the equation. That is, you can't find a number $x$ such that
$$
x - \frac{2}{x-1} = 1 - \frac{2}{x-1}
$$
How can you see this. First note that $x=1$ is not a solution because you can't divide by zero. Note then that if you add $2/(x-1)$ to both sides of the equation, then $x=1$. So the  only possible solution is $x=1$, but this doesn't work as we just figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to see this is to look at 1-D linear equations. All of them can be reduced to the form $ax=b$ for fixed constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. You are seeking $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that makes this equation true, i.e. $x$ would be a solution.

Note that if $a \ne 0$, then the equation admits a unique solution $x = b/a$.

Otherwise, you have 2 cases. If $b=0$, then the equation really reads $0 \cdot x = 0$, i.e. for any value of $x$ you plug in, the equation is true. There are infinite number of solutions in this case.

Finally, if $a=0$ and $b \ne 0$, no matter what value of $x$ you plug in, you cannot get a true statement, so there are no solutions.

In the higher dimensional cases, all linear equations fall into exactly one of these 3 categories: no solutions, unique solution, infinite number of solutions. However, it is possible to have a situation with infinite solutions which are not *all* elements of the vector space, e.g. in the equation $x=y$, you have an infinite number of solutions, which are one line in 2D plane, but not the entire plane...

In nonlinear cases, there are other elements. In your case, for example, the equation is undefined at $x=1$, so it is not a solution and the equation has no solutions at all.

Comment: but why it has no solution at x=1.

Comment: @mtg the expression has no solution at $x=1$ since both sides of the equation are *undefined* there. $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$ does not exist at $x=1$ since you cannot divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

$x=1$ is not a solution because both sides of the equation are undefined at $x=1$.

Comment: This is a comment - not an answer.

Comment: How is this not an answer? @FlybyNight

Comment: @JohnMa The question asks for an explanation of why some equations have no solutions. This "answer" addresses the one point where the OP says that $x=-1$ is a solution. It's a correction of the post, and not an answer to the question.

Comment: It's an answer to the first question: "if the equation has no solution then why it has no solution".  The only $x$ that you might think is a solution is $x=1$, but that is not a solution ...